# How do I draw a bounding box in OpenCV given a Keras prediction?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, resnet

My code is:

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

ret_val, frame = video_capture.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame,(224,224))
cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)
frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
frame = preprocess_input(frame)

preds = model.predict(frame)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
```

The results I get are:

```
Predicted: [('n04550184', 'wardrobe', 0.40715462), ('n04209239', 'shower_curtain', 0.09730709), ('n04005630', 'prison', 0.04603362)]
```

I don't have an `x, y, w, h` so I don't know where to draw the bounding boxes.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't using ResNet. ResNet has a FC layer that processes out the location information. Try to use YOLO instead. It is featured with very efficient location & object classification. Another solution to this is not to use Keras but to use the built-in Haar Wavelet Transforming Cascade of OpenCV. [This link](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) has all you need to know to train a OpenCV Haar Cascade.

Comment: There's no default application in keras for YOLO it seems? https://keras.io/applications

Comment: When I was using YOLO, I was still using Cpp to bridge the YOLO library and Python, now is more convenient, a native Python YOLO library being made.

Comment: There is more than one way to use trained models, one is from Keras-builtins(Keras applications), one is from outside the Keras library.

Comment: This looks like it's a full implementation. I just want to get a Yolo prediction given the image. Is there a library for that?

Comment: Google [:(](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299281/4228275) "keras object detection" if you want to stick with Keras. You were using a classification model.